# Subdomain server IP address could not be found

Tags: dns, domain, hosting, subdomain

Good day. I have a Centos Web Panel hosting and bought a domain from namecheap. Setting up my domain was easy and received no errors but when I created a subdomain for my domain, I am always prompted with the error ***"Site cannot be reached. Subdomain server IP address could not be found."***.

I have tried adding an A record with my subdomain that points to the IP Address of my hosting, also added CNAME with subdomain name that points to my domain.

```
Name                              Type       TTL        Value

subdomain.domain.com               A         14400      IP Address
subdomain                          CNAME     14400      subdomain.domain.com
```

Should I set up also my domain in my namecheap account to match this to work or am I missing some set up here?

Thanks.

Comment: Whose nameservers are you using? Whar URL are youbusing. Your use of "subdomain" and "subdomain.domain.com" is confusing. From a domains POV they are identical, but if you are browsing to just subdomain that assumes settings in your computers DNS. Also, dont use CNAMES here as they fo not behave like most people thonk - stick with A records.

Comment: @davidgo I am using the url format "subdomain.domain.com" with assigned nameservers from my hosting ns1.nameserver.com & ns2.nameserver.com. The above code done was just my assumption from the results I found in the internet. Thanks for correcting me btw.

Comment: In that case just delete "subdomain" and wait half a day.

Comment: @davidgo I just did what you have said and now it works. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need only:

> subdomain            A         14400      IP Address

Comment: Did what you said but didn't remove any not until I was told by davidgo. Still the answer should be the same with this. Thanks